# Best Way To Use Guava

Tags: java, guava

Which is the best way you think to use Guava?  Since, in the web site, the guys say that the interfaces are subject to change till they release 1.0.  Taking this into account, the code you write shouldn't depend directly on those interfaces, so, are you wrapping all the Guava code you call into some kind of layer or facade in our projects in order to, if those interfaces change, then you at least have those changes centralized in one place?

Which is the best way to go?  I am really interested in starting using it but I have that question hitting my mind hahah :)

Answer (score 22):

I'm not sure where you're getting that about the interfaces being subject to change until version 1.0. That was true with Google Collections, Guava's predecessor, but that has had its 1.0 release and is now a part of Guava. Additionally, nothing that was part of Google Collections will be changed in a way that could break code.

Guava itself doesn't even use a release system with a concept of "1.0". It just [does releases](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/downloads/list), labeled "r05", "r06" and so on. All APIs in Guava are effectively frozen unless they are marked with the [@Beta](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/annotations/Beta.html) annotation. If `@Beta` is on a class or interface, anything in that class is subject to change. If a class isn't annotated with it, but some methods in the class are, those specific methods are subject to change.

Note that even with the `@Beta` APIs, the functionality they provide will very likely not be removed completely... at most they'll probably just change how that functionality is provided. Additionally, I believe they're deprecating the original form of any `@Beta` API they change for 1 release before removing it completely, giving you time to see that it's changed and update to the new form of that API. `@Beta` also doesn't mean that a class or method isn't well-tested or suitable for production use.

Finally, this shouldn't be much of an issue if you're working on an *application* that uses Guava. It should be easy enough to update to a new version whenever, just making changes here and there if any `@Beta` APIs you were using changed. It's people writing *libraries* that use Guava who really need to avoid using `@Beta` APIs, as using one could create a situation where you're unable to switch to a newer version of Guava in your application OR use another library that uses a newer version because it would break code in the older library that depends on a changed/removed beta API.

Comment: Chris,  Thanks so much for your answer.  You are right, i read that the code is subject to change till version 1.0 but in the google-collections site, not in guava's site.  I agree with you reagarding the use of the @Beta annotation.  Thanks again!  Carlos.

Comment: Colin -- dude, you have seriously been paying attention!  Thanks for answering this with ... radical correctness.

Comment: I really wonder why they brought up this `@Beta` annotation. As it does not indicate a `not final` status the library behaves like any other library where you have to be aware of changes on new releases. That's the nature of new versions (I know that you should NEVER EVER change a public interface.... :-).

Comment: @K. Claszen: I'm not sure what you're saying. As I explained in this answer, `@Beta` _does_ indicate something that is not final and subject to change in future releases... things without `@Beta` will not change and can safely be used in other libraries.

Comment: @ColinD With _not final_ I meant a status that is not ready for production use (SNAPSHOT, Release Candidat, Milestone, ...). I first thought this would be indicated by `@Beta` but that is obviously NOT the case. @Beta annotated classes/methods are ready to use but will possibly change - as I understood. So - although not recommended for public interfaces - this is the normal life of software. I doubt that all not `@Beta` annotated classes are frozen and will never get deprecated, deleted or changed. So this annotation is confusing for me (and others)  - otherwise there would be no discussion.

Comment: @K. Claszen: All non-`@Beta` APIs _are_ frozen and, if deprecated, will only be removed 18 months after the release they are deprecated in. So there are some pretty strong guarantees about anything not annotated with `@Beta`.